# Не могу распарсить XML

Tags: c#, vkontakte-api

Получаю вот такой ответ от vk.com в формате xml:

```
<attachments list="true">
  <attachment>
    <type>wall</type>
    <wall>
      <id>4349</id>
      <from_id>-56918454</from_id>
      <to_id>-56918454</to_id>
      <date>1411324566</date>
      <post_type>post</post_type>
      <text> ... </text>
      <attachment>
        <type>photo</type>
        <photo>
          <pid>341408648</pid>
          <aid>-7</aid>
          <owner_id>-56918454</owner_id>
          <user_id>100</user_id>
          <src>http://cs624318.vk.me/v624318058/2e0e/yEDO4AvtdvU.jpg</src>
          <src_big>http://cs624318.vk.me/v624318058/2e0f/mFskYMTBN2w.jpg</src_big>
          <src_small>http://cs624318.vk.me/v624318058/2e0d/PMM2MFbQOXQ.jpg</src_small>
          <width>500</width>
          <height>353</height>
          <text />
          <created>1411324566</created>
          <post_id>4349</post_id>
          <access_key>90a17fdacd00db0f74</access_key>
        </photo>
      </attachment>
      <attachments list="true">
        <attachment>
          <type>photo</type>
          <photo>
            <pid>341408648</pid>
            <aid>-7</aid>
            <owner_id>-56918454</owner_id>
            <user_id>100</user_id>
            <src>http://cs624318.vk.me/v624318058/2e0e/yEDO4AvtdvU.jpg</src>
            <src_big>http://cs624318.vk.me/v624318058/2e0f/mFskYMTBN2w.jpg</src_big>
            <src_small>http://cs624318.vk.me/v624318058/2e0d/PMM2MFbQOXQ.jpg</src_small>
            <width>500</width>
            <height>353</height>
            <text />
            <created>1411324566</created>
            <post_id>4349</post_id>
            <access_key>90a17fdacd00db0f74</access_key>
          </photo>
        </attachment>
      </attachments>
      <post_source>
        <type>api</type>
      </post_source>
      <comments>
        <count>0</count>
        <can_post>0</can_post>
      </comments>
      <likes>
        <count>416</count>
        <user_likes>0</user_likes>
        <can_like>1</can_like>
        <can_publish>1</can_publish>
      </likes>
      <reposts>
        <count>95</count>
        <user_reposted>0</user_reposted>
      </reposts>
    </wall>
  </attachment>
</attachments>
```

Пытаюсь получить все элементы  :

```
var wallTexts = element.Document.Root.Elements("attachment").SelectMany(wall => wall.Elements("wall").SelectMany(text => text.Elements("text")));
```

Но в результате коллекция wallTexts всегда пуста. Не могу понять где же я ошибаюсь?

Comment: У вас документ иерархический. Вы с какого уровня хотити поднять тег text?

Comment: Мне нужен тег text на уровне тега <wall>. Тег text  на уровне <wall>/<attachment>/<photo> мне не нужен

Comment: Добавил изменения в свой ответ

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Для поиска элементов проще воспользоваться XPath-ом

```
var wallTexts = element.Document.Root.XPathSelectElements("./attachment/wall/text");
```

Но на самом деле, ваш первоначальный запрос выдаёт тот же результат, так что, предположу, что `element` из вашего кода - это элемент из *другого* XML-документа.

Comment: Через XPathSelectElements все заработало. Даже не знаю почему через просто Elements не работало. Кстати через XPathSelectElements действительно намного удобнее. Спасибо что подсказали.

Answer (score 4):

Чтобы понять, где вы ошиблись в сложном выражении - выведите куда-нибудь промежуточный результат на каждом шаге.

```
Console.Write("1\n{0}\n\n", element);
Console.Write("2\n{0}\n\n", element.Document);
Console.Write("3\n{0}\n\n", element.Document.Root);
Console.Write("4\n{0}\n\n", element.Document.Root.Element("attachment"));
Console.Write("5\n{0}\n\n", element.Document.Root.Element("attachment").Element("wall"));
Console.Write("6\n{0}\n\n", element.Document.Root.Element("attachment").Element("wall").Element("text"));
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var xdoc = XDocument.Parse(s);
if (xdoc.Document != null && xdoc.Document.Root != null)
{
    //"/attachments/attachment/wall/text"
    var wallTexts = xdoc.Document.Root.Elements("attachment")
        .SelectMany(wall => wall.Elements("wall"))
        .SelectMany(text => text.Elements("text"));

    //"/attachments/attachment/wall/attachment/photo/text"
    var wallTextsNew = xdoc.Document.Root.Elements("attachment")
        .SelectMany(x => x.Elements("wall"))
        .SelectMany(x => x.Elements("attachment"))
        .SelectMany(x => x.Elements("photo"))
        .SelectMany(x => x.Elements("text"));
}
```

Можно через `XPath`:

```
var list = xdoc.XPathSelectElements("/attachments/attachment/wall/text");

var listNew = xdoc.XPathSelectElements("/attachments/attachment/wall/attachment/photo/text");
```

Загрузить все теги `text` можно так:

```
var list = xdoc.Descendants(XName.Get("text"));
```

Comment: Скажите, а почему вы в метод `Elements` передали просто строку - а в метод `Descendants` - `XName.Get` от строки? В чем разница?

Comment: @PavelMayorov Можно передать строку. Она будет автоматически кастована к XNode. Для разнообразия :)

Comment: Это ваше "разнообразие" только запутывает.